# FBQ (Facebook Events) with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular

I have inserted the Facebook Pixel in my HTML and I need to call the FBQ function from an Angular Component. However, I'm having issues calling window.fbq trying to register the event, "bbq does not exist on type 'Window'.

Does anyone have implemented it? Any ideas how to call a js function in the index.html from an Angular Component?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Facebook advertising tracking pixels in Angular 2 / 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120510/using-facebook-advertising-tracking-pixels-in-angular-2-4)

Answer (score 5):

The answer might come a little too late, but here is how I implemented it:

I added the facebook pixel code to my index.html. Then I created a service that handles the tracking:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare const fbq;

@Injectable()
export class FacebookPixelEventTrackerService {

  constructor() { }

  public trackEvent(properties: Object) {
    if (typeof fbq === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', properties);
  }
}
```

Inject the service where you need it, and everything should work out. :)

Comment: So if the Facebook pixel script has not loaded at this point, this won’t track a pageview at all ...? Not sure I’d call that a proper “solution” to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

create one service and call it in your app.component.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FacebookPixelService {
        constructor() { }
        load() {
            (function (f: any, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
                if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                    n.callMethod ?
                        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
                }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
                n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
                t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            (window as any).fbq.disablePushState = true; //not recommended, but can be done
            (window as any).fbq('init', '<your id>');
            (window as any).fbq('track', 'PageView');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! how can I handle the typescript error with the parameters: n, t, s : implicitly has any type ? thank you